# Safari not rendering web-page correctly

Tags: macos, safari

Any idea why Safari (11.1.2) for macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 is not rendering this web-page correctly?

[image]

Comment: Poor connectivity. Reboot all your network hardware; router, modem, wifi, any hubs & switches; then the computers. Try again.

Comment: Additionally, please mention if this is happening with a specific web-page or all the web-pages. You could also try resetting local browser cache by going to `Safari → Clear History...`.

Comment: @Tetsujin the network I am on it's quite good...

Comment: @NimeshNeema I was indeed trying to understand some patterns, but it's not so easy... it seems it has issues here, with many SE pages for instance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine (iMac late 2015, macOS 10.13.6, Safari 11.1.2), the cause of the bad rendering was the AdBlock extension. I removed it, restarted Safari, and Safari rendered correctly. I then re-downloaded AdBlock, and Safari continues to render correctly.

I moved too fast doing this, and didn't note the version number of the AdBlock I removed, so don't know if the not-working AdBlock I removed was the currently-downloading version. In any event, the just-downloaded version doesn't interfere with Safari's rendering.

Comment: thanks -- I just had indeed the same idea before reading your answer and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable Develop Menu in Safari by going to `Safari → Preferences → Advanced`.

Now hit <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to reload the web-page from origin.

The CSS for the page is missing/unreachable thereby rendering it this way.

If the problem persists, wait for some time and try again.

Additionally, you can also try clearing local cache by going to `Safari → Clear History...`.

Comment: thanks, however  `empty caches` + `reload page from origin` is not working...

Comment: In that case it’s possible that the issue is from websites backend. As I mentioned if the problem persists, wait for some time and try again. You can also message the site webmaster if it is critical.

Comment: None of the suggestions fix the issue. It's interesting that the issue occurs on only one of my two computers, which both run the same software. It's also ironic that the issue only appears on stackexchange.com webpages.

Comment: Restarting in Safe Mode did not reform this behavior.